# How to read SEQ files produced by FLIR thermal infrared cameras?

Tags: python, seq, temperature, infrared, flir

I have some thermal infrared videos in .SEQ format captures with a FLIR camera. I can view them using FLIR Tools software, but I would like to instead read them into python, with every frame of the video being a numpy array containing temperature brightness values in each pixel.
I saw that the flirpy library (https://flirpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/seq.html) is able to covert .SEQ files to a different format, but I haven’t found any code examples for this, or any tool that can open the .SEQ files directly in python. If possible, I would prefer to work with the thermal files directly in python rather than covert them to a different file format.

Answer (score 0):

There ist a file sdk from FLIR:
https://github.com/gcathelain/thermalcognition/tree/master/FLIR%20Science%20File%20SDK

the FileSDK can also be downloaded from FLIR directly: [https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/~/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python](https://flir.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3504/%7E/getting-started-with-flir-science-file-sdk-for-python)
Then you can install it directly for different python versions or also buiild wheel-files for an easier usage.

This directly supports the read out of the .seq-files via the package fnv. For me this is working fine and much faster than splitting by marker, which is sometimes done.